# Recover Windows 7 bootloader and its original drive letter (C:) back

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I had Windows 7 installation, and my drive had following partition structure as I found in Gparted in Ubuntu LiveCD session.

- 100 mb system partition (Primary)
- Windows 7 partition (60 GB) (Primary)
- Data partition 1 (Primary)
- 25 GB unallocated space.
- Extended Volume.

  - Data Partition 2.
  - Data Partition 3.

Now, I attempted to Install Ubuntu in 25 GB partition, but installer didn't allowed me to install saying that I cannot have any additional primary partitions. Hence, I thought that 100 mb partition (which was primary) is not needed since it is created when we install Windows on a clean computer without any partitions existing. So I deleted that partition, and than proceeded with Ubuntu installation.

Everything went fine and I was even asked by Ubuntu installer to import any settings from existing Windows installation. But, when I restarted to boot into newly installed Ubuntu, I was not presented with boot menu to choose from booting into Ubuntu or Windows, and was directly booted into Ubuntu. I tried running `sudo update-grub2` but it didn't found my Windows installation. So, I booted from Windows install CD and tried to repair it from there, but it was unable to find my Windows installation. Also, `C:` was no longer the Windows partition, instead it was `E:`.

I know I might have made a mess, but how can I recover my Windows installation back as it was before Ubuntu installation, I'm fine in removing Ubuntu for now if it is required to get Windows back.

Thanks.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-7-100-mb-system-recovery-partition-missing/7b12184c-adac-4e69-a178-25f1877d75b5 suggests a repair, but it looks like you already tried that?

Comment: @john: Yes I've already tried that, as well played with `Bootrec` utility too.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.

While in Ubuntu copy the file /boot/grub/boot.img to Windows 7 partition "\" folder.

1. Use any Disk management tool and mark Windows partition as active.
2. Run Windows 7 StartUp Repair (from DVD/USB) up to 3 consecutive times with rebooting after each run.

Now you will have a booting Windows 7.

To add Ubuntu as boot choice to Windows 7 boot menu:

1. Download and install [Visual BCD Editor](http://boyans.net).
2. Create boot sector loader and amend device and path to point to file \boot.img (copied earlier from Ubuntu)

Comment: I had Ubuntu installed in a dedicated partition, adding its entry to Windows Bootloader will work? as per my knowledge, Windows Bootloader doesn't support any non-Windows OS (but now I doubt since this could be a workaround to copy `boot.img` to Windows). But I'll definitely give a try to your suggested method.